# Microsoft Word Find & Replace Wildcards (except this pattern)

Tags: replace, ms-word, wildcard

How can I use wildcards to find except this pattern.

For example, if the text is "html   html>", 
I can use "\<[a-zA-Z]@>" to find the pattern "`<`html`>`" or "`<`css`>`".

However, how can I find the opposite, excluding "`<`html`>`" or "`<`css`>`"?
"[!\<[a-zA-Z]@>]" does not return anything.

Answer (score 1):

`[!range]` can only be used with a range inside, meaning you can't write a regex inside `[!]`.

You could use it to do something like this : `[!<][a-zA-Z]@[!>]`

This will find every [a-zA-Z] that is not surrounded by `<>`

Comment: "[!<][a-zA-Z]@[!>]" still finds texts like "<html>" or "<css>". In other words, it doesn't exclude them and find the opposite.

Comment: There is another helpful alternative provided by somebody here: [link](http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/19270-find-replace-wildcards-except-pattern.html#post57846).